# Delete messages from Exchange 2007/2010 from .net

Tags: c#, .net, exchange-server-2007, exchange-server-2010

I am looking for suggestion on how I can connect to Exchange 2007/2010 with .net and delete all items in a give mailbox.

Thanks

Comment: Connecting to the server using IMAP should work.  If you want help you need to at least attempt it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can connect via EWS if you're running OWA. If you use the Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data namespace there's a "lot" of thing's you can do with little code. Plenty of information on the net too.